# JavaScript - Stop laser once its in its incrementation cycle

Tags: javascript, html, css

To see a working example simply copy code into notepad++ and run in chrome as a .html file, I have had trouble getting a working example in snippet or code pen, I would have given a link to those websites if I could get it working in them.

The QUESTION is; once I fire the laser once it behaves exactly the way I want it to. It increments with lzxR++; until it hits boarder of the game arena BUT if I hit the space bar WHILST the laser is moving the code iterates again and tries to display the laser in two places at once which looks bad and very choppy, so how can I get it to work so the if I hit the space bar a second time even whilst the laser was mid incrementation - it STOPS the incrementing and simply shoots a fresh new laser without trying to increment multiple lasers at once???

below is the Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #blueCanvas {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: black;
            width: 932px;
            height: 512px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        #blueBall {
            position: relative;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
        }

        #laser {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            width: 10px;
            height: 1px;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
        }

        #pixelTrackerTop {
            position: absolute;
            top: 530px;
            left: 20px;
        }

        #pixelTrackerLeft {
            position: absolute;
            top: 550px;
            left: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/
    ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);
        var topY = 0;
        var leftX = 0;
        var lzrY = 0;
        var lzrX = 0;

        function moveUp() {
            var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
            topY = topY -= 1;
            Y.style.top = topY;
            masterTrack();
            if (topY < 1) {
                topY = 0;
                Y.style.top = topY;
            };
            stopUp = setTimeout("moveUp()", 1)
                /**allows for progression of speed with additional key strokes**/
            topStop();
            stopConflictYup();
            console.log('moveUp');
        };

        function moveDown() {
            var Y = document.getElementById("blueBall");
            topY = topY += 1;
            Y.style.top = topY;
            masterTrack();
            if (topY > 500) {
                topY = 500;
                Y.style.top = topY;
            };
            stopDown = setTimeout("moveDown()", 1)
                /**allows for progression of speed     with additional key strokes**/
            topStop();
            stopConflictYdown();
            console.log('moveDown');
        };

        function moveLeft() {
            var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
            leftX = leftX -= 1;
            X.style.left = leftX;
            masterTrack();
            if (leftX < 1) {
                leftX = 0;
                Y.style.leftX = leftX;
            };
            stopLeft = setTimeout("moveLeft()", 1)
                /**allows for progression of speed with additional key strokes**/
            leftStop();
            stopConflictXleft();
            console.log('moveLeft');
        };

        function moveRight() {
            var X = document.getElementById("blueBall");
            leftX = leftX += 1;
            X.style.left = leftX;
            masterTrack();
            if (leftX > 920) {
                leftX = 920;
                Y.style.leftX = leftX;
            };
            stopRight = setTimeout("moveRight()", 1)
                /**allows for progression of speed with additional key strokes**/
            leftStop();
            stopConflictXright();
            console.log('moveRight');
        };

        function masterTrack() {
            var pxY = topY;
            var pxX = leftX;
            document.getElementById('pixelTrackerTop').innerHTML =
                'Top position is ' + pxY;
            document.getElementById('pixelTrackerLeft').innerHTML =
                'Left position is ' + pxX;
        };

        function topStop() {
            if (topY <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(stopUp);
                console.log('stopUp activated');
            };
            if (topY >= 500) {
                clearTimeout(stopDown);
                console.log('stopDown activated');
            };
        };

        function leftStop() {
            if (leftX <= 0) {
                clearTimeout(stopLeft);
                console.log('stopLeft activated');
            };
            if (leftX >= 920) {
                clearTimeout(stopRight);
                console.log('stopRight activated');
            };
        };

        function stopConflictYup() {
            clearTimeout(stopDown);
        };

        function stopConflictYdown() {
            clearTimeout(stopUp);
        };

        function stopConflictXleft() {
            clearTimeout(stopRight);
        };

        function stopConflictXright() {
            clearTimeout(stopLeft);
        };

        function shootLaser() {
            var l = document.getElementById("laser");
            var lzrY = topY;
            var lzrX = leftX;
            fireLaser();

            function fireLaser() {
                l.style.left = lzrX; /**initial x pos **/
                l.style.top = topY; /**initial y pos **/
                var move = setInterval(moveLaser, 1);
                /**continue to increment laser unless IF is met**/
                function moveLaser() { /**CALL and start the interval**/
                    var bcrb = document.getElementById("blueCanvas").style.left;
                    if (lzrX > bcrb + 920) {
                        /**if the X axis of the laser goes beyond the  

                               blueCanvas 0 point by 920 then stop incrementing the laser on its X   

                               axis**/
                        clearInterval(move);
                        /**if statement was found true so stop increment of laser**/
                    } else {
                        lzrX++;
                        l.style.left = lzrX;
                    };
                };
            };
        };

        function keyBoardInput() {
            var i = event.keyCode;
            if (i == 32) {
                shootLaser();
            };
            if (i == 38) {
                if (topY > 0) {
                    moveUp();
                };
            };
            if (i == 40) {
                if (topY < 500) {
                    moveDown();
                };
            };
            if (i == 37) {
                if (leftX > 0) {
                    moveLeft();
                };
            };
            if (i == 39) {
                if (leftX < 920) {
                    moveRight();
                };
            };
        };
        /**

    !! gradual progression of opacity is overall
    !! being able to speed up element is best done with setTimout
    !! setInterval is constant regards to visual speed
    !! NEXT STEP IS ARRAYS OR CLASSES 
    IN ORDER TO SHOOT MULITPLE OF SAME     ELEMENT? MAYBEE?


    var l = document.getElementById("laser");
    lzrX = lzrX += 1;
    l.style.left = lzrX;
    lzrY = topY += 1;
    l.style.top = lzrY;
    **/
    </SCRIPT>

</head>

<div id="blueCanvas">
    <div id="laser"></div>
    <div id="blueBall">

    </div>
</div>

<p id="pixelTrackerTop">Top position is 0</p>
<br>
<p id="pixelTrackerLeft">Left position is 0</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please only post relevant code on your question instead of a giant wall of code.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b956xqxt/  - Granted, I have no idea what the heck I'm looking at.

Comment: ^ The "Giant wall of code" is the full "game" so far, allowing the user to see exactly how it works. Omitting anything would prove opposite.

Comment: You will have to export the code into either a HTML doc as OP stated or place in a non-scrollable window. The Up, Down, Right, Left arrow keys and spacebar are used for movement.

Comment: @Illdapt Yes, that is the point because SO is not for debugging an entire application, but for specific problems and issues.

Comment: Yes i understand, its not my question, but to debug in this instance, we kinda need it all. That said, @Ghoyos, I would look into creating a new instance of the laser each time fired.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the `fireLaser()` function out of the `shootLaser()` function?

Comment: yes but i was forced to add fireLaser because of the setInterval, needing to come before "moveLaser()"

Comment: i was thinking maybee there is a way to detect the incrementaion is still ongoing? if thats possible then i can create a if statement that says if incrementation is occuring to stop and then start from the beginning?

Comment: or maybee a type of on/off switch? when the code beggins incrementing the switch gets turned ON but when the incrementation is done it switches a variable to OFF and then the if statement that detects the keystroke can be set to detect with the switch is on/off?

Comment: @Santi your js fiddle link doesn't work properly, its not firing laser at all, my code actually fires the laser.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 I cannot omit any css html or js being that the question deals with something that is moving on the X/Y axis of the page

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with using a variable called "g" and incrementing it once the laser is shot!

```
var g = 0;
function keyBoardInput() {
var i = event.keyCode;


  if (i == 32) {
  if (g < 1) {
  shootLaser();
  g++;
  };


  };
```